# How to add placeholder for my form XML fields in joomla

Tags: php, xml, forms, joomla

I am using Joomla inbuilt registration form and I added some fields to that form.

I need to add placeholder for my form but "placeholder" keyword is not working.

registration.xml

```
<field name="city" type="text" description="Enter your city" 
       label="City" required="true" size="10" filter="string" />
```

Comment: registration.xml   <field 
      name="city" 
      type="text"
   description="Enter your city"
   label="City"
   required="true"
   size="10"
   filter="string"

  />

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add a placeholder, you need to add the `hint` attribute, like so:

```
<field name="city" 
       type="text" 
       description="Enter your city" 
       label="City" 
       required="true" 
       size="10" 
       filter="string"
       hint="Placeholder here" />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: in Joomla 2.5  "hint" keyword is not working . its working properly in Joomla 3.0 .? what is the reason ? even Placeholder keyword all so not working .   ?

Comment: I believe this feature was added in Joomla 3.x. For Joomla 2.5, you will need to create a custom form field which overrides the standard "text" one: http://docs.joomla.org/Form_field#Custom_form_field_types

Comment: ok @Lodder .but tell me how to change the register button name . i tired a lot but i didn't get ant link or any style sheet ,please help

Comment: The register button name? If this is something different to your current question, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Add this in **edit.php** for a particular field:

`JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen','#jform_fieldname', null, array('disable_search_threshold' => 0, 'placeholder_text_multiple' =>'placeholder Value'));`

Answer (score 0):

```
<field name="mytextvalue" type="text" label="Enter some text" hint="Some placeholder about the field" />
```

For more details check Joomla documentation
https://docs.joomla.org/Text_form_field_type/3.2